# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

##### A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: supp
>
> Filename: models/Supplier_m.php
>
> Line Number: 18
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sikan_v2\application\models\Supplier_m.php
> Line: 18   Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\sikan_v2\application\controllers\Supplier.php
> Line: 42   Function: add
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sikan_v2\index.php   Line: 315   Function:
> require_once

## A Database Error Occurred

> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'name' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `supplier` (`name`, `phone`, `address`,
> `description`) VALUES (NULL, '81213176824', 'xa', NULL)
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/sikan_v2/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 692
>
> My Controllers: controllers/Supplier.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Supplier extends CI_Controller {

    
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        check_not_login();
        check_admin();
        $this->load->model('supplier_m');
    
    } 


    public function index()
    {
        $data['row'] = $this->supplier_m->get();
        $this->template->load('template', 'supplier/supplier_data', $data);
    }

    public function add()
     {
        $data['row'] = $this->supplier_m->get();
        $supplier = new stdClass();
        $supplier->supplier_id = null;
        $supplier->name = null;
        $supplier->phone = null;
        $supplier->address = null;
        $supplier->description = null;
        $data = array(
            'page' => 'add',
            'row' => $supplier
        );
        $this->template->load('template', 'supplier/supplier_form', $data);
    }

    public function process()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post(null, TRUE);
        if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
            $this->supplier_m->add($post);
        }

        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('Data berhasil disimpan');</script>";
        }
        echo "<script>window.location='".site_url('supplier')."';</script>";
    }

    public function del($id) {
        $this->supplier_m->del($id);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('Data berhasil dihapus');</script>";
        }
        echo "<script>window.location='".site_url('supplier')."';</script>";
    }
}
```

My View: views/supplier_form.php

```
<section class="content-header">
      <h1>Suppliers
        <small>Pemasok Barang</small>
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="active">Suppliers</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">Add Supplier</h3>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="<?=site_url('supplier')?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat">
                   <i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Back
                </a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <form action="<?=site_url('supplier/process')?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Supplier Name *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="supp" value="<?=$row->name?>" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Phone *</label>
                            <input type="number" name="phone" value="<?=$row->phone?>" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <textarea name="addr" class="form-control" required <?=$row->address?>></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Description</label>
                            <textarea name="desc" class="form-control" <?=$row->description?>></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" name="<?=$page?>" class="btn btn-success btn-flat">
                               <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Save
                            </button>    
                            <button type="Reset" class="btn btn-flat">Reset</button>    
                        </div>
                
                    </form>

                </div>

            </div>
         </div>
         
            
    </div>

    </section>
```

My Models: models/Supplier_m.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Supplier_m extends CI_Model {

    public function get($id = null)
    {
        $this->db->from('supplier');
        if($id != null) {
            $this->db->where('supplier_id', $id);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    } 

   public function add($post)
   {
    $params = [
        'name' => $post['supp'],
        'phone' => $post['phone'],
        'address' => $post['addr'],
        'description' => empty($post['desc']) ? null : $post['desc'],
    ];
    $this->db->insert('supplier', $params);

   }

    public function del($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('supplier_id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('supplier');
    }

}
```

please help me solve this error, I have tried but still can't

Comment: There are 3 different errors mentioned in this post, in total. Which one are you actually asking about? The ones about columns not being null are clear - you must provide the database a value for those columns when you insert a row, but you aren't doing that. Either that, or you must reconfigure the database so that column has a predefined default value it can insert when there is no value provided by your PHP code.

Comment: And the undefined index one simply means that $post["supp"] doesn't exist. Although it's unclear why, because `name="supp"` appears to exist in your form. Maybe you are not using that version of the form? Or maybe that function is called by something else? Have you tried to do any debugging? I don't see any evidence of that in your post, particularly.

Comment: You need to check the form used for adding the supplier as it seems the text box named supp was not sent back to the server causing both error messages.

Comment: Oh I see. now I understand where it went wrong. Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

**For first error**

you have open your Supplier_m  model and **find function ->  public function add($post)**

and at the beginning of the function you have to check the data which you have send from controller like

```
public function add($post){
  echo "<pre>";print_r($post);die;
}
```

you will get the actual result of post data

**For second error**

Open your phpMyadmin (databse) edit the table and select the checkbox as NULL beside the name column , find the below image may be it will help you

[image]